# Facing problem in opencv background noise subtraction and movement detection

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0, noise-reduction

I'm working on a project which requires detection of people and due to the complexity of the system, I decided to use movement detection.

I faced some problems and upon asking on stack overflow, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63931113/14241197)  seemed the best.

So I implemented the algorithm in the following steps:

1. Implement saliency on the input video
2. Applied K-means clustering
3. Background Subtraction
4. Morphological Transformation

Here is the code

```
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#i wanted to try different background subtractors to get the best result.
fgbg=cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
fgbg1 = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()

h = cap.get(4)
w = cap.get(3)
frameArea = h*w
areaTH = frameArea/150


while(cap.isOpened()):
    #time.sleep(0.05)

    _,frame=cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
    image=frame 

    ################Implementing Saliency########################
    saliency = cv2.saliency.StaticSaliencySpectralResidual_create()
    (success, saliencyMap) = saliency.computeSaliency(image)
    saliencyMap = (saliencyMap * 255).astype("uint8")
    #cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    #cv2.imshow("Output", saliencyMap)

    saliency = cv2.saliency.StaticSaliencyFineGrained_create()
    (success, saliencyMap) = saliency.computeSaliency(image)
    saliencyMap = (saliencyMap * 255).astype("uint8")

    threshMap = cv2.threshold(saliencyMap.astype("uint8"), 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    # show the images
    #cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    #cv2.imshow("saliency", saliencyMap)
    #cv2.imshow("Thresh", threshMap)
    
    kouts=saliencyMap
    #cv2.imshow("kouts", kouts)
    ##############implementing k-means clustering#######################
    
    clusters=12
    z=kouts.reshape((-1,3))

    #covert to np.float32
    z=np.float32(z)

    #define criteria and accuracy
    criteria= (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER,5,1.0)

    #apply k-means
    ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(z,clusters,None,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

    #converting back the float 32 data to unit 8 and making the image
    center=np.uint8(center)
    res=center[label.flatten()]
    kouts=res.reshape((kouts.shape))
    

    cv2.imshow('clustered image',kouts)

    ############applying background subtraction#######################
    fgmask=fgbg.apply(kouts)
    fgmask1=fgbg1.apply(kouts)
    cv2.imshow('fg',fgmask)
    cv2.imshow('fgmask1',fgmask1)
    #as i said earlier, i wanted to get the best background subtractor
    
    #########################morphological transformation#####################
    #Below i tried various techniques to get the best possible result
    
    kernel=np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    
    erosion=cv2.erode(fgmask1,kernel,iterations=1)
    cv2.imshow('erosion',erosion)
    dilation=cv2.dilate(fgmask1,kernel,iterations=1)
    cv2.imshow('dilation',dilation)

    gradient = cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask1, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)
    cv2.imshow("gradient",gradient)

    opening=cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask1,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel)
    closing=cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask1,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel)

    cv2.imshow('opening',opening)
    cv2.imshow('closing',closing)
    
     #########for detection of contours##################
    contours0, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(erosion,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for cnt in contours0:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if area > areaTH and area<frameArea*0.50:                        
            M = cv2.moments(cnt)
            x,y,f,g = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
            img = cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+f,y+g),(0,255,0),2)
            cv2.imshow('Original',frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
    if k == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried this algorithm on this [video](https://youtu.be/06vFemzgMuc) but still there was a lot of noise in the output. I previously thought that the problem might be in the quality of the video but when I did cv2.VideoCapture(0), the problem still persist and the code doesn't seem to remove the noise and the situation I'm working in, has sometimes high noise.

Tell me any suggestions or where did I go wrong or a different approach to the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I spent sometime trying to see if something can be done with noise reduction, but I believe you already tried many of the known techniques in OpenCV. My opinion is to approach your problem using neural networks as they will be more accurate detecting the objects.

I created a Colab notebook, to illustrate this:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rBrcu46sfo0F7fsQf4BC9hKoXTk_wNBk?usp=sharing

Even with this simple approach, it's possible to detect objects: persons and clothing. You can set a criteria that can just consider the top 10 items. As a bus entrance has a limit of people that can enter at the same time.

This is not a final solution because I am using a general purpose detector. This can be improved in your application by training the network with your video inputs. Labeling will be required but I believe this will give you the most accurate results.

I also think for the challenge to track the people that are inside the bus and the ones entering. For that you can take track the rectangles. There is an excellent example using dlib: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/10/22/object-tracking-with-dlib/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Since i haven't really worked with neural networks before, it will take time to understand your code. This might be a  good start as well. Also i thought of another approach which is using yolo for detecting people and then counting the no. of boxes. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Yes give YOLO a try, same principle. Yolo is also a neural network.